# How to avoid creating a new Swagger schema definition in a schema of type array?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc

I have the following Java classes:

`State.java`

```java
@ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(name = "State"))
public class State extends ArrayList<Operation>
{}
```

`Operation.java`

```java
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Data
@Jacksonized
public class Operation
{
   @Schema(required = true)
   @JsonProperty("op")
   private String op;
}
```

This generates the following schema for `State` with an extra schema for `Operation`:

```json
"State":{"type":"array","items":{"$ref":"#/components/schemas/Operation"}}
```

Now, I don't want to generate an extra schema for `Operation` and instead include the properties of it under `items`. So, in the end I want to generate the following:

```json
"State":{"type":"array","items":{{"type":"object","properties":{"op": string}}}}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

I'm using Springdoc with `io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:jar:2.2.8`